# How to show saved data inside multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-edittext, save

**Intro**

Hi guys, currently I am working on a question-form app. In the MainActivity users can add an item after which a QuestionListActivity opens. Clicking on the first item in that list opens the Main2Activity. This activity exists of 3 fragments which all include one question (Edittext). The data implemented by the user in the fragments is saveable. After answering and saving questions, each form appears in the MainActivity as a list. Clicking on these items brings them back to the QuestionListActivity after which clicking on the first item should open the fragments again with their saved data already shown.

**Problem**

After saving the fragments, the string to the MainActivity is succesfull, eg. the Title as set by saving the first fragment (which asks for the name of the form). Therefore, the saving to my Utilities class was succesfull. The problem is, clicking on a saved item in the MainActivity and then on the first item in the QuestionList to open the Main2Activity (fragments with questions), opens the fragments but with empty EditText fields where the saved data should be shown to view them or make changes.

**Question**

How is it possible to show the saved data inside multiple fragments instead of in just one activity and what am I doing wrong? And is it recommended to use the same format when using 8 questions (one fragment per question)?

(I couldn't find the right question to use on StackOverFlow, because almost every question about this subject is about the instance state ed. but this isn't a problem in my project)

**Codes**

Here is my Main2Activity and one fragment(Frag1). The other fragment I have setup the same way as Frag1. I am probably doing something wrong in the fragment java classes but I am unsure what. Hopefully, someone can help me.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

private String mNoteFileName;

private Note mLoadedNote;
private EditText title, question2, question3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    title = findViewById(R.id.note_et_title1);

    question2 = findViewById(R.id.note_et_question2);

    question3 = findViewById(R.id.note_et_question3);

    String title;
    String question2 ;
    String question3;
    mNoteFileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("NOTE_FILE");
    if(mNoteFileName !=null && !mNoteFileName.isEmpty()) {
        mLoadedNote = Utilities.getNoteByName(this, mNoteFileName);
        if(mLoadedNote !=null) {
            title = mLoadedNote.getTitle();
            question2 = mLoadedNote.getQuestion2();
            question3 = mLoadedNote.getQuestion3();
        }
    }

    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragments.add(Frag1.newInstance(title));
    fragments.add(Frag2.newInstance(question2));
    fragments.add(Frag3.newInstance(question3));

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_note_new, menu);
    return true;
}

private void saveNote() {
    Note note;

    if(title.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if(mLoadedNote ==null) {
        note = new Note(System.currentTimeMillis(), title.getText().toString(), question2.getText().toString(), question3.getText().toString());

    }else {
        note = new Note(mLoadedNote.getDateTime(), title.getText().toString(), question2.getText().toString(), question3.getText().toString());

    }

    if (Utilities.saveNote(this, note)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "not enough space", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_note_save:
            saveNote();

            break;
    }

    return true;
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> mFragments;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
private static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "text";
private EditText mEtTitle;

public static Frag1 newInstance(String message) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    Frag1 fragment = new Frag1();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
public Frag1 () {

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
    mEtTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.note_et_title1);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mEtTitle.setText(bundle.getString(EXTRA_TEXT));
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Vraag 1, bv naam" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_et_title1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to slighlty change your current approach.

First create helper method `newInstance` in each fragment which will return the instance of that fragment. For example Frag1

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    private static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "text";
    private EditText mEtTitle;

    public static Frag1 newInstance(String message) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        Frag1 fragment = new Frag1();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public Frag1 () {

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
        mEtTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.note_et_title1);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            mEtTitle.setText(bundle.getString(EXTRA_TEXT));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

In `SectionsPagerAdapter` pass the list of Fragment.
For the reference hereby modified `SectionsPagerAdapter`.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> mFragments;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
}
```

Then change the call

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),<List of Fragments>);
```

Hereby sharing modified Activity#onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    String title = "";
    String question2 = "";
    String question3 = "";
    mNoteFileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("NOTE_FILE");
    if(mNoteFileName !=null && !mNoteFileName.isEmpty()) { 
        mLoadedNote = Utilities.getNoteByName(this, mNoteFileName);
        if(mLoadedNote !=null) {
            title = mLoadedNote.getTitle();
            question2 = mLoadedNote.getQuestion2();
            question3 = mLoadedNote.getQuestion3();  
        }
    }

    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    fragments.add(Frag1.newInstance(title));
    fragments.add(Frag2.newInstance(question2));
    fragments.add(Frag3.newInstance(question3));

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer sir, but I still have a problem. Right over here it stil says variables might not have been initialized. Can you see what I am doing wrong? After that I think this might work!     (I changed my codes)               List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(Frag1.newInstance(title));
        fragments.add(Frag2.newInstance(question2));
        fragments.add(Frag3.newInstance(question3));

Comment: what is the error you do have ? make sure you have created newInstance method for other two fragment as well Frag2 and Frag3 similar to Frag1

Comment: I did, the error I get: error: variable title might not have been initialized, error: variable question 2might not have been initialized, error: variable question3 might not have been initialized.

Comment: Initialize them with null or empty, have updated the same in answer as well

Comment: When I apply the changes I get an null object reference error in my saveNote part when I want to save my note in the emulator. But it is working for opening and viewing saved items I already have!

Comment: what is null reference there ? we haven't modified save note method right ?. Please keep sharing full information, so that we can save iteration of messaging

Comment: In private void saveNote he cannot resolve title, question 2 and question 3. If this problem is solved you solved my problem!

Comment: after `setContentView` try to initialize your views with the view id for example `title = findViewById(R.id.title);` You must have this issue in the beginning itself. I think you should had to mention this too in the question

Comment: I accepted your first answer, because it did solve my question. I can now view my already saved items inside the fragments. Only the saving is a problem right now and when I initialize my views, I get the error that he cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: Share your layout file activity_main2, we can solve this too

Comment: but in that layout file I can no see any edit text, did you share wrong one ? there must be som fields note_et_title1,note_et_question2,note_et_question3

Comment: I still get a null object reference inside my public void saveNote. Therefore I didn't initialized title etc right. Should I change String title = ""; to String title = findViewById(R.id.note_et_title1); ? Probably not, but I don't understand why it is still the same error. I already initialized them...

Answer (score 0):

You should use Shared Preferences or Database to save your data and show it.